# Prove that $5 \mid 3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am working right now through a book: Number Theory: A Lively Introduction with Proofs, Applications, and Stories
And I cant connect 5 to $3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}$
[image: img]

Comment: It's false for $n=1$! Shouldn't it be $5$ divides $3^{2n+1}+2^{2n+1}$ instead?

Comment: No it is not $3^5 + 2^3 = 251 $

Comment: @MathOverview it is not http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E(2n%2B1)+%2B+2%5E(n%2B1)+for+n+%3D+%5B1..10%5D

Comment: Ops! It's true for $n=4$. But some direct checks actually point out that the result is generally false.

Comment: Its from the book, might have typos! I have no clue how to connect 5 to the other term. Its not deep in the book. Chapter 3

Comment: I had a typo: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E(3n%2B1)+%2B+2%5E(n%2B1)+for+n+%3D+%5B1..10%5D

Comment: $3 \cdot 27^{n}+2 \cdot 2^{n}= 3 \cdot(25+2)^n+2 \cdot 2^n=3 \cdot 25 \cdot(25^{n-1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{1}\cdot 2^{n-1})+3 \cdot 2^n + 2 \cdot 2^n$